# Read Rows But search first

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

- I want to make an import system that will look into one Datasource and copy new records into another DataSource.
- Monthly I want to copy some tables data from one datasource to another datasource

SourceTableName : `srcTable`
DestinationTableName : `destTable`

Suppose first month in source table I have:

> Id      Name
>  1       john
>   3       Rahul
>  5       Andrew

All three rows Will be copy into `desTable`

Suppose Second Month in Source Table I have

> Id      Name
>  1       John
>   3       Rahul
>  5       Andrew
>   6       Vikas
>  7       Sonam
>   8       Divya

Firstly Sql Should get the last Row of `desTable` 
and match that row into `srcTable` 
and extract all new records from `scrTable` and copied into `desTable`

.....

Please let me know how I can write query for fulfill above purpose. If there is shorter approach, that would be helpful too.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: This is fairly easy to do in SSIS, have you got it available? If so have a look at Slowly Changing Dimensions, or using the `MERGE` statement (which would be my preference)

Comment: Do you only care about inserting rows that don't exist in the destination table?  What about updates or deletes that occur in the source table after they've been initially sent to the destination table?

Comment: Source table rows will not be changed...

Comment: Yup I only want to insert new rows which doesn't exist the destination table...

Answer (score 0):

Since you only care about adding new records, and don't need to handle updates or deletes...  You can simply add the record from the source table if it doesn't exist in the destination table:

```
INSERT INTO destTable (ID, Name)
SELECT s.ID, s.Name
FROM 
    srcTable s 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN destTable d ON d.ID = s.ID
WHERE
    d.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored procedure for do this action and execute that every time you want.
for this action you can from bellow query:
(Part 1 for insert new data, Part 2 for update change data)

```
Insert Into DestinationTable(ID, Name)
Select  ID, Name
    From    SoiurceTable
    Where   Not Exists
            (Select *
                From    TDestinationTablest
                Where   DestinationTable.ID =   SoiurceTable.ID)
Go
Update  DestinationTable
    Set DestinationTable.Name  =    SoiurceTable.Name
    From    DestinationTable, SoiurceTable
        Where   DestinationTable.ID     =   SoiurceTable.ID
```

I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks .. one more question .. can we Display how many new rows inserted ??